# grails : how to pass params in remoteFunction

Tags: grails

I want to a param using remoteFunction of grails.

**HTML**

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="profittable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Date</th>
                              <th>Profit</th>
                              <th>Delete?</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> 

                <g:each in="${dailyProfit}" var="dp">
                    <tr onclick="<g:remoteFunction action='edit' params="[date:${dp.date}]"></g:remoteFunction>" >
                        <td><g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="${dp.date}"/></td>
                        <td>
                                                    <g:formatNumber number="${dp.profit}" type="currency" currencyCode="PHP" format="###.##" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <g:form controller="dailyProfit" action="delete" >
                                                        <g:hiddenField name="date" value="${dp.date.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}" />
                                                        <g:actionSubmit class="delete" value="Delete" >
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                        </g:actionSubmit>    
                                                    </g:form>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> URI /SampleGrailsApp/dailyProfit/index Class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
>   Message Attribute value quote wasn't closed (action='edit'
>   params="[date:${dp.date}]").

**ACTIONS FOR EDIT**

The remoteFunction tag is inside every tr of my table. The plan is, if the row is clicked, the edit page will appear

```
def edit() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(params.date);
    def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.findByDate(date)
    render view:"edit" , model:[dailyProfit : dailyProfit]
}

 def update() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(params.date);
    def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.findByDate(date)
    if(dailyProfit){
        dailyProfit.properties = params
        dailyProfit.save(flush:true)
    }
    list() 
}
```

What is the proper way of passing parameters using remoteFunction tag of grails?

Comment: Have a look - http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Comment: @user1690588 I already but this isn't working either. <tr onClick="${remoteFunction( controller:'dailyProfit', action:'edit', params:'\'date\'=${dp.date}')}" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also a valid syntax:

```
<tr onClick="<g:remoteFunction action='edit' params="${[param1: 'value', param2: 0]}"></g:remoteFunction>">.....</tr>
```

Note that the code will translate into an Ajax call with the parameters you indicate. Being an Ajax call, you wont see the page change.

If you want to send the user to the edit page when the row is clicked one option is the following:

```
<tr onclick='document.location = "<g:createLink action='edit' params="${[date: dp.date]}"/>" '> ... </tr>
```

Comment: When I tried the the 2nd format I get this error, Cannot get property 'date' on null object .. :( Thanks

Comment: It is up to you to understand which date you want to pass to the edit action. In your code You have a loop: <g:each in="${dailyProfit}" var="dp">: it is expectd that dailyProfit is a list of objects and inside the loop you refer to the object with dp. If for some reason you have some null objects in the list, you can use the safe navigation operator: instead of dt.date use dt.?date

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this .

```
<tr onclick = "${remoteFunction(
    controller: 'xyz',
    action: 'edit',update:'divId',
    params: [date: dp.date])}" >
```

Comment: hi, I tried using the format shown above but nothing happened when I clicked the rows. Do you have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: hi, yes its working, I checked on the logs and I see the query it made. but why is it that this part is not run **render view:"edit" , model:[dailyProfit : dailyProfit]** and I stay on the profitTable page. Thanks

Comment: @user3714598  You are using ajax call show you should use update attribute of remoteFunction to update desired div. See my updated answer.

Comment: yes! it works! and aside from that, the page cached. :| Thank you :)